# vegan::ordiR2step() doesn't find best-fit model

Tags: r, vegan

The vegan package includes the `ordiR2step()` function for model building, which can be used to identify the most important variables using the R2 and the p-value as goodness of fit measures. However for the dataset I was recently working with the function doesn't provide the best-fit model.

```
# data
RIKZ <- read.table("http://www.uni-koblenz-landau.de/en/campus-landau/faculty7/environmental-sciences/landscape-ecology/Teaching/RIKZ_data/at_download/file", header = TRUE)

# data preparation
Species <- RIKZ[ ,2:5]
ExplVar <- RIKZ[ , 9:15]
Species_fin <- Species[ rowSums(Species) > 0, ]
ExplVar_fin <- ExplVar[ rowSums(Species) > 0, ]

# rda
RIKZ_rda <- rda(Species_fin ~ . , data = ExplVar_fin, scale = TRUE)

# stepwise model building: ordiR2step()
require(vegan)
step_both_R2 <- ordiR2step(rda(Species_fin ~ salinity, data = ExplVar_fin, scale = TRUE),
                       scope = formula(RIKZ_rda),
                       direction = "both", R2scope = TRUE, Pin = 0.05,
                       steps = 1000)
```

Why does `ordiR2step()` not add the variable *exposure* to the model, although it would increase the explained variance?

If `R2scope` is set FALSE and the p-value criterion is increased (`Pin = 0.15`) it adds the variable *exposure* corretly but throws the following error:

```
Error in terms.formula(tmp, simplify = TRUE) : 
  invalid model formula in ExtractVars
```

If `R2scope` is set TRUE (`Pi = 0.15`) *exposure* is not added.

*Note: This might seem more as a statistic question and therefore more suitable for [CV](https://stats.stackexchange.com/). However I think the problem is rather technical and better off here on SO.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read the `ordiR2step` documentation: it will tell you why `exposure` is  not added to the model. The help page tells that `ordiR2step` has three stopping criteria. The second criterion is that "the adjusted R2 of the ‘scope’ is exceeded". This happens with `exposure` and therefore it was not added. This second criterion will be ignored if you set `R2scope = FALSE` (also documented). So the function works like documented.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I should have checked the **Details** of the documentation earlier. However the documentation says you should use `R2step = FALSE` and not `R2scope = FALSE` to ignore the 2nd criterion. After the documentation `R2scope = FALSE` only enables the calculation of the adj. R2 if the number of predictors s higher than the number of observations. Do the parameters have changed over time?

Comment: `R2step` was an error in documentation, and now corrected in github (along with the `Error in terms.formula()` reported in the message).